# debugging the server part of the shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've tried to run this app several times, but the server part of the code doesn't work at all, even though it should be complete. The UI part works perfectly; however, when I attempt to run the server part, it just stops. I can't really see the issue
I would be grateful if you could look at the code.

```
ui<-pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Statistical analysis"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('file1', 'Select your file',
              accept = c(
                'text/csv',
                'text/comma-separated-values','.csv',
                '.sas7bdat'
              )
    ),
    splitLayout(
      textInput("subvar","Subset Variable:"),
      
      textInput("subval","Subset Value:")),
    splitLayout(
      textInput("dep","Dependent variable:"),
      textInput("indep","Independent variable:")),
    selectInput("varlist","Pick Treatment
variable:",choices=c(colnames(data()))),
    selectInput("Model","Model:",
                list("Linear regression" = "lm",
                     "Logistic regression" = "logistic",
                     "Survival analysis" = "surv",
                     "Anova test" = "anova",
                     "Chisquare test" = "chisq",
                     "Correlation" = "corr",
                     "Bootstrap CI" = "BCa")),
    radioButtons("type", "Select the plot file
type",choices=list("png","pdf"))),
  # Show the output and plot
  mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("caption")),
    plotOutput("myPlot"),
    downloadButton("save1", "Save the plot"),
    verbatimTextOutput("regSum")))
```

Server

```
server<-function(input, output, session) {
 # Import data
 data1 <- reactive({
 inFile <- input$file1
 if(is.null(file)){return()} [1]
 read_sas(inFile$datapath)
 })
 observeEvent(input$file1,{
 updateSelectInput(session,"varlist",choices=c(colnames(data1())))
 })
 # Compute the forumla text
 formulaText <- reactive({
 paste(input$dep,"~", input$indep)
 })
 output$caption <- renderText({
 formulaText()
 })
# Data
 new_data<-reactive({
raw_data <- data1()
 if (input$Model == 'surv') {
 df<-data.frame(
 Time = raw_data[[input$dep]],
 trt = raw_data[[input$varlist]],
 cen = raw_data[[input$indep]],
 sub = raw_data[[input$subvar]]
 )
 if (input$subval == "") { df2<-df }
 else { df2<-subset(df,sub==input$subval) }
 return(df2)
 }
 if (input$Model == 'logistic') {
 df<-data.frame(
 y = raw_data[[input$dep]],
 trt = raw_data[[input$indep]],
 sub = raw_data[[input$subvar]]
 )
 if (input$subval == "") { df2<-df }
 else { df2<-subset(df,sub==input$subval) }
 return(df2)
 }
# Statistics
 new_fit<-reactive({
 if (input$Model == 'surv') {
 fit<-survfit(Surv(Time , cen) ~ trt , data = new_data())
 return(fit)
 }
 if (input$Model == 'logistic') {
 fit<-glm(y ~ factor(trt), data = new_data(), family = "binomial")
 print(paste('Odds ratio:',exp(coef(fit))))
 return(fit)
 }
# Graph
 new_plot<-reactive({
 if (input$Model == 'surv') {
 graph<-ggsurvplot(new_fit(), risk.table = TRUE, pval = TRUE, data =
new_data())
 return(graph)
 }
 if (input$Model == 'logistic') {
 graph<-ggplot(new_data(),aes(y))+geom_bar()+facet_wrap('trt')
+labs(x=input$dep)
 return(graph)
 }
# Generate the plot
 output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
 new_plot()
 })
# Generate the summary of analysis
 output$regSum <- renderPrint({
 summary(new_fit())
 })
# Save the plot
 output$save1 <- downloadHandler(
 filename = function() {
 paste("myplot",input$type,sep=".")
 },
 content = function(file){
 if(input$type=="png") png(file)
 else pdf(file)
 print(new_plot())
 dev.off()
 })
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, ending in the middle of the `new_data` reactive block, and then you have nested reactive blocks in there. It would also help if you used an indent style that would help recognize this (and it helps visualize code flow in general, though that might be more subjective).

Comment: Scratch that. Almost *all* reactive blocks are not closed out properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will suffice: your code is missing close `})` in just about all `reactive(.` blocks. Additionally, you are not covering most of your `input$Model` possibilities, which means most of your reactive blocks return nothing, perhaps by-design, perhaps something else.

Try this code. Notice that indentation, while subjective, provides a clearer context of what "close" `})` is tied to which `reactive({`. In the end, if you ever see any nesting of `reactive`, `observe`, or `render*`, you're doing something wrong.

```r
server<-function(input, output, session) {
  # Import data
  data1 <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if(is.null(file)){return()} [1]
    read_sas(inFile$datapath)
  })
  observeEvent(input$file1,{
    updateSelectInput(session,"varlist",choices=c(colnames(data1())))
  })
  # Compute the forumla text
  formulaText <- reactive({
    paste(input$dep,"~", input$indep)
  })
  output$caption <- renderText({
    formulaText()
  })
  # Data
  new_data<-reactive({
    raw_data <- data1()
    if (input$Model == 'surv') {
      df<-data.frame(
        Time = raw_data[[input$dep]],
        trt = raw_data[[input$varlist]],
        cen = raw_data[[input$indep]],
        sub = raw_data[[input$subvar]]
      )
      if (input$subval == "") { df2<-df }
      else { df2<-subset(df,sub==input$subval) }
      return(df2)
    }
    if (input$Model == 'logistic') {
      df<-data.frame(
        y = raw_data[[input$dep]],
        trt = raw_data[[input$indep]],
        sub = raw_data[[input$subvar]]
      )
      if (input$subval == "") { df2<-df }
      else { df2<-subset(df,sub==input$subval) }
      return(df2)
    }
  })
  # Statistics
  new_fit<-reactive({
    if (input$Model == 'surv') {
      fit<-survfit(Surv(Time , cen) ~ trt , data = new_data())
      return(fit)
    }
    if (input$Model == 'logistic') {
      fit<-glm(y ~ factor(trt), data = new_data(), family = "binomial")
      print(paste('Odds ratio:',exp(coef(fit))))
      return(fit)
    }
  })
  # Graph
  new_plot<-reactive({
    if (input$Model == 'surv') {
      graph<-ggsurvplot(new_fit(), risk.table = TRUE, pval = TRUE, data = new_data())
      return(graph)
    }
    if (input$Model == 'logistic') {
      graph<-ggplot(new_data(),aes(y))+geom_bar()+facet_wrap('trt') +
        labs(x=input$dep)
      return(graph)
    }
  })
  # Generate the plot
  output$myPlot <- renderPlot({
    new_plot()
  })
  # Generate the summary of analysis
  output$regSum <- renderPrint({
    summary(new_fit())
  })
  # Save the plot
  output$save1 <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("myplot",input$type,sep=".")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      if(input$type=="png") png(file)
      else pdf(file)
      print(new_plot())
      dev.off()
    }
  )
}
```